# In a probability space, if $A = B = \Omega$, are A and B independent?

Tags: probability

**Question**: Let $A = \Omega$ and $B = \Omega$. Are $A$ and $B$ independent?

My response is no, because independence means that $P(A) \cdot P(B) = P(A|B) \cdot P(B)$. Assuming we are in the discrete case for ease, $P(A) \cdot P(B) = 1\ / \ \Omega ^{2}$ whereas $P(A|B) \cdot P(B) = 1 \cdot (1\ / \ \Omega ^{2})$.

Am I right in thinking this?

Comment: How exactly are you defining $\Omega$? The expression $\Omega^2$ right now does not make sense if $\Omega$ is some form of a set.

Comment: if $\Omega$ is the set of probability space the answer is yes, because $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(\Omega)=(\mathbb{P}(\Omega))^2=1$

Comment: In fact, in $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}), \Sigma\in\mathcal{F}$ is independent of itself if and only if $\mathbb{P}(\Sigma)=1$ or $0$.

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo - Yes, and $P(\Sigma) \in \{0, 1\}$ if and only if $\Sigma$ is independent of any set $\Sigma' \in \mathcal{F}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an intuitive argument that may help you think about independence (without the formula).

Intuitively, $A$ and $B$ are independent when knowing that one of them happened doesn't affect the probability that the other happened. $A = \Omega$ means "one of the possible outcomes happened for sure". That doesn't change the probability of $B$, which also means "one of the possible things happened for sure".

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming $\Omega$ is the universal set. Also we know that events $A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if $P(A)\cdot P(B) = P(A \cap B)$. So in this case, we have $P(\Omega) = 1$ and $\Omega \cap \Omega = \Omega$, therefore 
$$P(\Omega)\cdot P(\Omega) = P(\Omega)$$ holds. Thus, they are independent.